# Find the set of sub-sequential limits of a bounded sequence with infinite range

Tags: analysis

Given a bounded sequence ${X_n}$ with infinite range $[a,b]$,
is it possible to prove that the set of all sub-sequential limits is also $[a,b]$.

My reasoning is as follows:

Every point in range $[a,b]$ is a limit point.
Take any point from $[a,b]$, e.g. $c$. $c$ is a limit point.
Choose $n_1$ such that $d(c,X_{n_1})<1$.
Choose $n_i$ where $i>1$, such that $d(c,X_{n_i})<\frac{1}{i}$.
We show that there is a sub-sequence converging to $c$.

Update: Following Coffeemath's comment, I realise that the domain is a countable infinity while the range is an uncountable infinity. However, reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis proof for theorem 3.6(a), an infinite range $E$ is possible but I wonder how can we ensure that $E$ is a countable infinity especially since we can show that there are limit points in $E$ hence are there not uncountable number of punctured neighbourhoods around the limit point that is non-empty?

Rudin's theorem 3.6(a) - If ${p_n}$ is a sequence in a compact metric space $X$, then some sub-sequence of ${p_n}$ converges to a point of $X$.

His proof -

Let $E$ be the range of ${p_n}$. If $E$ is finite then there is a $p∈E$ and a sequence ${n_i}$ with $n_1<n_2<n_3<...$, such that

$p_{n_1} = p_{n_2} = p_{n_3} = ... = p$.

The subsequence $\{p_{n_i}\}$ so obtained converges evidently to $p$.

If $E$ is infinite, Theorem 2.37 (see below) shows that $E$ has a limit point $p∈X$. Choose $n_1$ so that $d(p,p_{n_1})<1$. Having chosen $n_1,...,n_{i-1}$, we see from theorem 2.20 (below) that there is an integer $n_i>n_{i-1}$ such that $d(p,p_{n_i})<\frac{1}{i}$. Then $\{p_{n_i}\}$ converges to $p$.

Theorem 2.37 - If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$.

Theorem 2.20 - If $p$ is a limit point of a set $E$, then every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of $E$.

Comment: Assuming $a<b,$ since $[a,b]$ is uncountable there is no bounded sequence with that range.

Comment: Apologies, it did not occur to me that this is not possible, do you happen to have a link that could elaborate on that a bit more or if you could outline the reason why such a bounded sequence does not exist, thank you!

Comment: A sequence $\{X_n\}$ has a finite or countably infinite range because that range can be covered by the real numbers $X_1,X_2,\cdots .$ So it cannot be all of $[a,b]$ assuming $a<b,$ since the latter is not countable. (one doesn't need boundedness for this argument)

Comment: @coffeemath thank you for the reply, I got it, but I also wonder does Rudin's proof for theorem 3.6(a) in his Principles of Mathematical Analysis assume a range that is uncountable since a limit point in an infinite range would assume an uncountable number of punctured neighbourhoods that are non-empty?

Comment: I don't have Rudin's book. Maybe you could include the relevant theorem and proof [or a link to it (not to a really long part of the text, just the relevant statement and proof)].

Comment: No problem, I will include his proof in the question

Comment: @coffeemath I have included Rudin's proof for reference. I imagined my initial question while studying this proof from Rudin. I would be very grateful if you could point out how the second part of his proof (dealing with an infinite range) avoids an uncountable infinity range. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: Let $X$ be the set of reals consisting of $0$ along with each number $1/n$ ($n=1,2,\cdots .$) Then let $p_n=1/n$ and note the only limit point of $p_n$ is $0$ which by construction lies in the set $X$ we defined. [$X$ is a metric space under restriction of the usual metric on the reals.]

For Rudin's second part of proof, $p$ is $0$ (only thing it could be). The rest of Rudin's argument is clear, in this example.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I see how the range can be countably infinite now. However, I imagine other $p$ might be possible such as a trivial example of $p_n = (1+(1/n))$ converging to $p=1$?

Comment: Yes, one could make an example by letting $X$ be the set of terms of any convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$ of distinct reals along with its limit, and $p_n=x_n.$